# Attached links to posts in the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I was hacking on a quick side project and I noticed that the graph API doesn't let you see the link of posts in a group.

For example: [this](https://graph.facebook.com/201636233240648_256839641053640) graph object has no information about a link. The [actual post](https://www.facebook.com/groups/animatedgifs/256839641053640/), however, has an attached gif.

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible with the graph API?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. What's even stranger is that with a valid access token you still cannot see the `link` information on that graph object.  I wonder if this has a deeper issue below it.  You should log it as a bug at http:developers.facebook.com/bugs and report back with the bug # here.